# Angularjs multiple file upload

Tags: angularjs

```
<input file-model="ad.File"
                 type="file"
                 class="form-control"
                 ng-required="true"
                 name="file"
                 ng-show="ad.Type"/>
```

My project stuck on multiple file upload with angularjs one file upload working fine but i can't upload multiple files. Searched well but can't find solution.

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: when i try to select files only i select one file

Answer (score 1):

You are missing [multiple](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp) attribute on your file input. It should be:

```
<input file-model="ad.File"
             type="file"
             class="form-control"
             ng-required="true"
             name="file"
             ng-show="ad.Type"
             multiple/>
```